# How can I change the before/after border colors for Angular CSS breadcrumbs with triangles?

Tags: css, angular

How to change style for before/after in Angular?

I'm trying implement breadcrumbs with triangles using before/after in the CSS, as shown in this tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Relevant snippets:

```css
.breadcrumb li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 65px;
  background: hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid hsla(34, 85%, 35%, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, I'm using it as a directed flow, something like:

This flow starts with Main_Category highlighted and other 2 parts dark, and there's a underneath that you can select from. On select, Sub_Category becomes highlighted and another pops up.

My question is how to change the before/after border colors if they're pseudo-elements? So from the tutorial, I think can do this on the main part:

`<li><a href="#" ng-style="background: {{color}}">Home</a></li>`

But there's no where for me to set ng-style for before/after, and the triangle colors end up unchanged.